# How can I get .html URL suffixes in permalinks?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I have never seen that the page ending up in wordpress with ".html ending", but some how i also feels that this page/blog is build upon wordpress - 
http://www.nytimes.com/2014/04/12/opinion/sunday/raising-a-moral-child.html

My Questions: If indeed this is a wordpress system how come ".html" is coming in the URLS end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short: You don't need `.html` ending.

`.html` ending can be easily archive by setting in Options > Permalink or using plugin like Custom Permalink.

But that's just personal style. Having `html` or not is now just different in length of URL. For me, the shorter one is better. It's has no effect on SEO score. In the past, `.html` ending is some kind to distinguish between archive and single/page, but now the Search Engine is smart enough to now the page is archive or single. So why don't we use shorter URL.

Comment: Ok Means their is no need, but if one wants then this is achievable in wordpress, right?

Comment: as I say above, `.html` ending can be easily archive by setting in `Options > Permalink` or using plugin like `Custom Permalink`.